# What's wrong with my shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-exec

I have a shell script which has a for loop that prints the value of an array element.
The array size is 2 but when running the for loop with that array I'm not getting proper output.

Here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

arry=$(ls /home/developer/.ssh/  | grep "\.pub")
declare -a ARR
i=0
for key in $arry
do
  ARR[i]=$(echo $key | sed 's/.pub//g')
  i=$((i+1))
done
echo ${#ARR[@]}
## the below for loop is not iterating as expected
for pri in $ARR
do
 echo $pri
done
```

Now instead of giving the output

```
2
a
heroku
```

The above code produces:

```
2
a
```

What is wrong with the above shell code?

I'm relatively new to shell script so pardon my code I you feel it not good

Attaching screenshot of the output
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
arry=(/home/developer/.ssh/*.pub)

ARR=(${arry[@]%%.pub})    # strip the extensions

echo "${#ARR[@]}"

for pri in "${ARR[@]}"
do
    echo "$pri"
done
```

Use globs instead of `ls`.

Use arrays instead of strings.

Quote variables when they are expanded.

Comment: That it thanks for the answer but could you explain what wrong with my script

Comment: @user1328293: `for pri in "${ARR[@]}"` is the correct way to iterate over an array instead of `for pri in $ARR`.

Comment: More specifically, `$ARR` expands to the *first element* of ARR, so it was iterating over just the first element.  `"${ARR[@]}"` is the correct way to get *all* elements.